# Magento 1.9.x to Magento 2.x migration with all customer, order, reviews and ratings

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

Magento 1.9.x to Magento 2.x migrations with all customers, order, reviews and ratings, The payment detail and order detail?

Comment: https://magecomp.com/blog/migrating-magento-1-x-to-magento-2-0/
This can help you, or give the try to these guys for helping migration 
https://magecomp.com/magento-2-upgrade-migration.html

Comment: DId you solve your task?

Comment: yes solved ....

Comment: This migration tool is perfect for you: [https://next-cart.com/product/magento-to-magento/](https://next-cart.com/product/magento-to-magento/). It can migrate all your required data + taxes, invoice...

Comment: ok i try it this tool

Answer (score 1):

I think there is way to get service or use tool

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html

http://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento2-data-migration-tool/

https://www.magecomp.com/magento-2-upgrade-migration.html

http://www.mageworx.com/magento2-migration

https://magecomp.com/blog/migrating-magento-1-x-to-magento-2-0/

Can also use below free modules

https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool

https://github.com/magento/code-migration

Comment: Export the customers detail table in database in the Magento 1.9  and Import the that customers detail table in Magento 2.. and any change in table structures

Comment: are any option in download csv in the Magento 1.9 and upload the Magento 2