# How To migrate Magento 1 to 2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento-2.1, magento-enterprise, migration

Hello guys can you please guide me how to migrate **Magento 1.9 to 2.1.3** 
I can't find perfect solution for **migrate from 1 to 2** 
any ready made extension available so please give me the extension URL 
and how to migrate from **Magento 1.9 to 2.1.3** Step by Step.

Comment: Have you gone through this ? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/migrate/migrate.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [magento 1.9 to 2 migration with all customer, order, reviews and ratings](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150375/magento-1-9-to-2-migration-with-all-customer-order-reviews-and-ratings)

Answer (score 0):

There are some extension that can help you to migrate your `magento 1` store to 
`magento 2`. Some are paid extension like `cart2cart`.

You can also use extension/app developed by `Ubertheme` using `Yii`. This is available at github free of cost. Please see below link to download extension.

[Download UberTheme Data Migrate Extension](https://github.com/ubertheme/magento2_data_migration)

Comment: this tool is install in magento 1 ? 

because i m new in magento ..that's whay  :(

Comment: and without any extension can i move all products , users and order to Magento 2 ?

Comment: @AlkeshGoswami This is a SaaS tool that can help you migrate from Magento 1 to Magento 2: [https://next-cart.com/product/magento-to-magento/](https://next-cart.com/product/magento-to-magento/). You don't need to install it anywhere, just run the migration.